Mount returns reason given by server: No such file or directory
Yes! Another boring mount question :-) :
My home server had crashed - probably because 1 of the HDD has crashed - after removing it the server went back on without issues. note that there are 2 other drives in the server as well :
Disk2_1TB
Disk4_1TB
And the new disk :
Disk3_500GB (which replaces Disk3_250GB)
Now the fun starts.
The broken drive was a 250GB HDD drive - the new drive is a SDD drive.
Put it in - formatted it to NTFS, created a label changed details in the smb.conf - added an entry in /etc/fstab to mount it on boot and all is ok on server side.
**entry in Fstab (server):**
UUID=67EAAB18626D809E /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB auto defaults 0 0 

**Entry in smb.conf**
comment = Disk3_500GB
path = /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB
browseable = yes
read only = no
writeable = yes
valid users = me, you,
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700

**lsblk**
sdb                         8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                      8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/rabbithole/Disk2_1TB
sdc                         8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                      8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/rabbithole/Disk4_1TB
sdd                         8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdd1                      8:49   0 465.8G  0 part /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB

**sudo blkid -o list**
/dev/sdd1  ntfs    Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB 67EAAB18626D809E
/dev/sdb1  ntfs    sdb_1       /mnt/rabbithole/Disk2_1TB 3DF5D0052AA8C8AB
/dev/sdc1  ntfs    SDD_1       /mnt/rabbithole/Disk4_1TB 54D70D411ABCA6A2

you can see here that (swapping SATA cables inside the server) sdc1 USED to be SDD_1 - but i cannot imagine the label of the drive making all the difference.
ls -l 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dec 24 13:09 Disk2_1TB
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Dec 30 11:31 Disk3_500GB
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov 21  2023 Disk4_1TB

now on the client side :
**/etc/fstab**
192.168.178.100:/mnt/rabbithole/Disk2_1TB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk2_1TB nfs4 defaults,x-systemd.after=wait-for-ping.service 0 0
192.168.178.100:/mnt/rabbithole/Disk4_1TB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk4_1TB nfs4 defaults,x-systemd.after=wait-for-ping.service 0 0
192.168.178.100:/mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB nfs4 defaults,x-systemd.after=wait-for-ping.service 0 0


**output sudo mount -a**
mount.nfs4: mounting 192.168.178.100:/mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory

Now when i use Dolphin and go to 'Shared Folders (SMB)' and go to smb//192.168.178.100 it finds the drive perfectly and i am able to browse the files within.
Now being the smartass i then tried using the cli to see if i could play a bit with the mount command - but without success.
  326  sudo mount -t nfs4 //192.168.178.100/mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/
  327  sudo mount -t nfs4 //192.168.178.100/mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/ /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/
  328  sudo mount -t nfs //192.168.178.100/mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/
  329  sudo mount -t nfs4 //192.168.178.100:mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/
  330  sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.178.100:mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/
  331  sudo mount 192.168.178.100:mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB /mnt/rabbithole/Disk3_500GB/

all without succes - i did get a -2 error somewhere - but not sure when i got that one.
then i had the idea to mount 1 level higher :
192.168.178.100:/mnt/rabbithole/ /mnt/rabbithole/ nfs4 defaults,x-systemd.after=wait-for-ping.service 0 0

Which gives me Disk2 and Disk4 drives in dolphin (but not the 500GB drive)
so - i think i did everything right - but for some (probably stupid) reason the disk cannot be mounted as it was not there.
Hope that anybody can help me out here.
Regards
Diet

I may have simply not had enough coffee yet, but I'm confused why you are trying to mount the volume from the client side as nfs when you appear to have shared it via smb?

@steeldriver Excellent remark. Guess it's not the coffee but more my lack of making the right choices. In the past I used to connect to the server using smb, also because my wife used a windows laptop which kind of forced me to use smb as an easy solution (and being unaware of other possible choices) then I learned that mounting in ubuntu, on my own kubuntu laptop, had several performance gains so I went that way for my laptop.  So in a way people can skip this as it is not a 'real ' issue as there already is a workaround, but I really prefer the mounting option for my laptop

... so to share the new disk via NFS as well as CIFS (SMB) you would need to edit your NFS server export table too (should be in /etc/exports)

feels like an idiot

@steeldriver thank you so much for this answer.
